# Collect all the zip files having same name and zip it again Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

I have a directory which contains multiple logs for same script with timestamp. I want to collect all the zip files and make a new zip.

```
Directory Structure:
Test_1_Run_Logs_06-12-2018_10_15_35.zip
Test_1_Integration_Logs_06-12-2018_10_15_35.zip
Test_1_Interface_Logs_06-12-2018_10_15_35.zip
Test_2_Run_Logs_06-12-2018_10_30_35.zip
Test_2_Integration_Logs_06-12-2018_10_30_35.zip
Test_2_Interface_Logs_06-12-2018_10_30_35.zip
```

I have separated all the files having same name. The zip file is not moving all the zip files. How to do it in ruby

```
Code
require 'fileUtils'
require 'zip'
scriptNameArr = []
logFolder = 'C:/Users/Desktop/logs/'
copyFolder = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Test/Ruby Test/copyFolder/"

# Collect all the files present in logFolder separating by timestamp
Dir.entries("#{logFolder}/").each do |fName|
    unless (File.directory? "#{logFolder}#{fName}")
         scriptNameArr << fName.split("/").last.split(/_\d+-\d+-/)[0]
    end
end
scriptNameArr.uniq!

# Create a new zip into copy 
scriptNameArr.each do |scriptName|
    zipName = "#{copyFolder}#{scriptName}.zip"
    Dir.mkdir(copyFolder) unless (Dir.exist?(copyFolder))
    FileUtils.rm(zipName) if File.exist? (zipName)
    Zip::File.open(zipName, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
         Dir.glob("#{logFolder}#{scriptName}*") { |file|
             fileName = file.split("/").last
             zip.add(fileName, logFolder)
         }
    end
end
```

It is creating empty zip everytime. What should i do to copy the zip file and paste in new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss filename when `zip.add(fileName, logFolder)`

Correct:
`zip.add(fileName, File.join(logFolder, fileName))`

Happy Coding! :)